# How to save cropped images in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab-cvst, parking

I'm trying to identify the parking spaces after cropping. Here is my code. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

```
 I=imread('carsnew.jpg');
a=63; b=115;
for i=1:10
im=imcrop(I,[a,b,75,133]);
grayImage=rgb2gray(im);
binary=im2bw(grayImage);

figure,imshow(binary);
a=a+85;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have got each and every parking slot cropped for the provided image  but I want to give a unique id to each and every figure and then compare the the empty parking slot and occupied. such that I can know the Number of vacant spaces.

Comment: Hi, you have as your title that you would like to save cropped images in MATLAB. To do so you can add the following lines to your code as follows:
figure,imshow(binary);
filename = sprintf('parking_slot_%d.png', i);
saveas(gcf, filename, 'png')
a=a+85;
end
Please update your question if you require further assistance. Thanks!